# Any idea why i'm always getting "Sat 17th" date (Calendar) - java?

Tags: java, date, calendar

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   JsonWeatherTime time = new JsonWeatherTime();
   String date = time.formatDate(Long.valueOf(1454691600));  //Todays date
    System.out.println(date);

  }

 private String formatDate(long milliseconds){
    StringBuffer dateBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Calendar     calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
    switch(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)){
    case Calendar.MONDAY: dateBuffer.append("MON, ");
    break;
    case Calendar.TUESDAY:dateBuffer.append("TUE, ");
    break;
    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:dateBuffer.append("WED," );
    break;
    case Calendar.THURSDAY:dateBuffer.append("THUR, ");
    break;
    case Calendar.FRIDAY:dateBuffer.append("FRI, ");
    break;
    case Calendar.SATURDAY:dateBuffer.append("SAT, ");
    break;
    case Calendar.SUNDAY:dateBuffer.append("SUN, ");
    break;
    default:dateBuffer.append("N/A");
  }

 String day_of_week = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    if(day_of_week.equals("1") | day_of_week.equals("21") | day_of_week.equals("31") ) day_of_week += "st";
    else if(day_of_week.equals("2") | day_of_week.equals("22") ) day_of_week += "nd";
    else if(day_of_week.equals("3") | day_of_week.equals("23")) day_of_week += "rd";
    else day_of_week += "th";
 //Log.d("JSONPARSE", "THE VALUE OF THE DATE ISSSSSS" + day_of_week);
  dateBuffer.append(day_of_week);
  return dateBuffer.toString();
 }
```

I'm parsing json weather data from the OpenWeatherMap api, and no matter the value i parse for the date (given in milliseconds through json), the calendar returns a date of Sat 17th. I'm not entirely familiar with working with dates, but the json returns a millsecond string in UNIX time, and if i pass in todays date (1454691600), the string should read (Fri, 6th), though it returns (Sat, 17th). Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: So, your value is `1454691600` and you use `calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);` ... do you really think that "1454691600" are the _milliseconds_ counted since 01/01/1970? What if they are the _seconds_? Would your current problem then makes sense?

Comment: If that time were in milliseconds it would represent roughly 17 days, rather than 46 years

Comment: @Boris, thanks for the constructive comment...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Neither `SimpleDateFormat` nor date/time API will output date using `st`, `nd`, `rd`, and `th` suffixes, and that seems to be the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

The value `1454691600` is in *seconds*, not milliseconds.

```
Date date = new Date(1454691600 * 1000L);
SimpleDateFormat dateFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d");
System.out.println(dateFmt.format(date)); // prints: Fri, 5

System.out.println(date); // prints: Fri Feb 05 12:00:00 EST 2016
```

Comment: Wow, okay that was about "1000" times easier. Pun intended. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

The JSON returns value in a **seconds**, not in a milliseconds.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String date = formatDate(Long.valueOf(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(
            1454691600)));  //Todays date
    System.out.println(date); // FRI, 5th

}
```

This code works fine and prints expected date: **FRI, 5th**

Answer (score 1):

The other Answers are correct, your number seems to be whole seconds rather than a count of milliseconds-from-epoch.

## java.time

FYI, you are using old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. They have proven to be troublesome and poorly designed. Java 8 and later supplants those old classes with the java.time framework.

### Parse Number

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. In code below, notice the `L` to mark a numeric integer as a `long` (64-bit integer).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1454691600L );
```

### Time Zone

Time zone is crucial in determining a date. If you do not specify the time zone, both the old classes (as seen in your Question) and java.time classes silently apply the JVM’s current default time zone. Better to be explicit about the time zone you desire/expect.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

### Localized Name Of Day

To get the localized name of the day, use the [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum. We ask for [Québec French](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH) here to make the point. You could specify [Locale.ENGLISH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ENGLISH) or Locale.US, and so on. As with time zone, I strongly recommend always specifying your desired/expected Locale rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default Locale which can change at any moment even during runtime.

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.from( zdt );
String nameOfDay = dayOfWeek.getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ); // Or Locale.ENGLISH or Locale.US, and so on.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant + " | zoneId:  " + zoneId + " | zdt: " + zdt + " | dayOfWeek: " + dayOfWeek + " | nameOfDay: " + nameOfDay );
```

> instant: 2016-02-05T17:00:00Z | zoneId:  America/Montreal | zdt: 2016-02-05T12:00-05:00[America/Montreal] | dayOfWeek: FRIDAY | nameOfDay: ven.

### Ordinal Indicator

The java.time framework does not help you get the [ordinal indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator) such as "st" or "th" as far as I know. You will have to do the same kind of code as seen in your Question.